# Custom display with dotted lines

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to create a screen like this:

[image: image of the requirement]

I have to divide width and height into 8 equal parts with lines (if possible, dotted lines). How to do that?

Here is my current code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.load);

    display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;

    equal_parts_width = width/8;
    equal_parts_height = width/8;

    Log.i("", width + " <==> " + height + " == "
        + equal_parts_width + "==" +equal_parts_height );   
}

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();  

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);         
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++) {
                canvas.drawLine(0, equal_parts_height*i,
                    width, equal_parts_height*i,  paint);
                canvas.drawLine(equal_parts_width*i, 0,
                    height, equal_parts_width*i,  paint);
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar yes 8 or 10 is fixed value.

Comment: so you can use background imge right?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar no need to use any background image. i need problematically implement this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Paint.setpathEffect(PathEffect effect)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setPathEffect%28android.graphics.PathEffect%29) with [DashPathEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/DashPathEffect.html).

From docs: The intervals array must contain an even number of entries (>=2), with the even indices specifying the "on" intervals, and the odd indices specifying the "off" intervals.

```
paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{on, off}, 0));
```

And add this to your DrawView constructor

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);         
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{on, off}, 0));
}
```

EDIT complete code..

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();  

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);         
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
        float width = canvas.getWidth();
        float height = canvas.getHeight();
        float size = height/(7*2); //just use 14 it's for convenience here
        paint.setStrokeWidth(WIDTH);
        paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{size, size}, 0));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, size*i,
                width, size*i,  paint);
            canvas.drawLine(size*i, 0,
                height, size*i,  paint);
        }        
    }

}
```

you should be able to take this and simply alter it to fit you needs.
You can also create rounded dots with this code.

```
 paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
 paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
 paint.setDither(true);
 paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Comment: no need on and off conditions just i want to draw lines(if possible doted lines) in 10 equal parts.

Comment: on means the part of the line where is the dot and off is the gap between your dots..
to make it even just use same values for both on and off